# MySQL data to a python dict structure

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dictionary

The structure of my mysql table looks like this:

```
id | mid | liters | timestamp
1 | 20 | 50 | 2016-10-11 10:53:25
2 | 30 | 60 | 2016-10-11 10:40:20
3 | 20 | 100 | 2016-10-11 10:09:27
4 | 30 | 110 | 2016-10-11 09:55:07
5 | 40 | 80 | 2016-10-11 09:44:46
6 | 40 | 90 | 2016-10-11 07:56:14
7 | 20 | 120 | 2016-04-08 13:27:41
8 | 20 | 130 | 2016-04-08 15:35:28
```

My desired output is like this :

```
dict = {

20:{50:[2016-10-11 10:53:25,2016-10-11 10:53:25],100:[2016-10-11 10:53:25,2016-10-11 10:09:27],120:[2016-10-11 10:09:27,2016-04-08 13:27:41],130:[2016-04-08 13:27:41,2016-04-08 15:35:28]},

30:{60:[2016-10-11 10:40:20,2016-10-11 10:40:20],110:[2016-10-11 10:40:20,2016-10-11 09:55:07]}

40:{80:[2016-10-11 09:44:46,2016-10-11 09:44:46],90:[2016-10-11 09:44:46,2016-10-11 07:56:14]}
        }
```

If `50:[2016-10-11 10:53:25,2016-10-11 10:53:25]` (when you don't have a previews timestamp and you need to duplicate) it's hard to make, just a `50:[2016-10-11 10:53:25]` can be ok.
How can I extract this to a python dict from my db table.

I tryed something like :

```
query_all = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mid,liters,timestamp) FROM `my_table` GROUP BY mid  ORDER BY mid "
```

But I don't know how to order this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` may have own `ORDER BY`

e.g .

```
GROUP_CONCAT(mid,liters,timestamp ORDER BY liters)
```